# Rare Lego Mursten box. Where can I sell it and what would I ask?

Tags: vintage

Found this box in a rural vintage shop in northern Sweden. I’ve come to understand these were among the first boxes of Lego sold, for the Scandinavian market. This particular one seems to be for the Swedish market, the price list on the inside is in Swedish.

This should be with someone passionate about Lego, not gathering dust on a shelf in my home.

What could it be worth, and where might I find buyers?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Your box is a 700/1 Swedish box (a 700/2 doesn't have that much blue space above and below the image).  Value depends on what is inside as well: the bricks/windows/doors, as well as if the interior cardboard partitions are still there.

Also, I know several collectors (with deep pockets) who would be interested if you still want to sell this set.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks Stack Exchange, Gary; nice to see you here!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge, Gary! Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Comment: Hey Gary, your earthlink adress does not seem to work. My reply below.

Answer (score 6):

As Syberion mentioned, Gary Isztok is *the* authority on old LEGO sets. Mursten (Bricks in most Scandinavian languages) is the old name for the LEGO line (after Automatic Binding Bricks but before LEGO System) at a time when the product wasn’t yet globally availaible.

I would strongly recommend reaching out to him (he has a facebook page as well, look for the Unofficial LEGO Sets/Parts Collectors Guide) - maybe send him the picture of the box? He is in touch with a large group of old LEGO set collectors - this could offer you a different sales venue than putting this on eBay or a local site.

Nice find!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Gonna sign up for Eurobricks and see if I can find Gary somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is [700_2-1: Gift Package (Lego Mursten)](https://brickset.com/sets/700_2-1/Gift-Package-(Lego-Mursten))

Source: [The Unofficial LEGO Sets/Parts Collectors Guide by Gary Istock](http://legocollectorsguide.weebly.com/)

Can't find any price information, so i would make a post on [Eurobricks](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/) to determine value and/or find buyers

also i found this post about restoring a 1954 [700/1 set](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/82227-restoring-a-very-old-lego-set/) ,
this could provide some more background

Comment: Thanks, man! I haven't been able to find a single photo anywhere online of this set. Regrettably, it does not have the instructions booklet, but (I think) most of the pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Dude.
Most of the website don't even have information on it.
here's what i have found:

- It's from after 1950, but before 1955.
- It should be filled with individual pieces.
- I couldn't find any record of selling Lego Mursten
- Lego became famous after 1955, meaning this is very rare.

I also agree that you should go on Eurobricks.
I found a dude who appears very knowledgeable, so see if you can contact him.
https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/profile/1550-lego-historian/

Here is discussion about a similar set, and then about the see further down. however, none of them have the wide blue trim like on your set.
https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/77152-unknown-lego-sets/&tab=comments#comment-3011350

Here it is on Brickset:
https://brickset.com/sets/700_1_1-1/Individual-2-x-4-Bricks

Now this is a cool one, the cover for the box art is from a promotional video:
http://brickfetish.com/timeline/1952.html

If that things got instructions you are looking pretty set.